# How do I support streaming in WSFederationHttpBinding?

Tags: wcf, streaming, ws-federation

I have a wcf service which is used to upload and download large files to server. I'm using MTOM message encoding and I want to use streamed transfer mode. But we are using wsFederationHttpBinding. How do I support streaming in wsFederationHttpBinding?

My WCF Service web.config code is given below,

```
<wsFederationHttpBinding>
 <binding  name="UploadserviceFederation"
                      messageEncoding="Mtom"
                  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                      maxDepth="2147483647"
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>

          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <!-- Ping token type MUST be SAML 1.1, do not change -->
            <message 
              issuedTokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1" negotiateServiceCredential="false">
              <!-- TODO: You must put the proper issuer URN of the Ping STS; normally this would be the Ping base URL -->
              <issuer address="https://my-issuer.com" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileUploadSTSBinding" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>

      </wsFederationHttpBinding>


<customBinding>
        <binding name="FileUploadSTSBinding">
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="false"
              keyEntropyMode="ServerEntropy" requireSecurityContextCancellation="false"
              requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
          </security>
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a few years, so I don't know if this still helps, but I came across this post while trying to figure out the same issue, so it might help someone.

As it turns out, it's actually pretty simple..once you get the dance just right.

Probably the easiest thing (and what I tried first) is to inherit from WS2007FederationHttpBinding. As it turns out, it has a GetTransport method that's virtual, so you can override it and return an instance of HttpsTransport with TransferMode set to Streamed:

```
public class FileUploadSTSBinding : WS2007FederationHttpBinding
{
    protected override TransportBindingElement GetTransport()
    {
        return new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
        {
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed
        };
    }
}
```

However, doing this revealed something else: since my binding was no longer a recognized binding type, svcutil didn't treat it like a WS2007FederationHttpBinding anymore, but rather as a custom binding, which lead to the client-side configuration being generated as a stack of binding elements rather than using the shortcuts provided by the federation binding:

```
    <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_ISdk">
                    <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport"
                        requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10">
                        <issuedTokenParameters keyType="BearerKey">
                            <additionalRequestParameters>
                                <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                    <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
                                </trust:SecondaryParameters>
                            </additionalRequestParameters>
                        </issuedTokenParameters>
                        <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
                        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
                    </security>
                    <textMessageEncoding />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
```

..which shows what the underlying binding elements actually *are*, which lets you tweak them all you like. And, as it turns out, they're really not that different from the actual binding since the only really special part is the security element, and it doesn't change much.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something, but how do we apply the rest of the configuration to FileUploadSTSBinding?
I know this is old.. but i am in the same situ!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you're using the approach in the first box, all of the settings you would normally have access to in the config file should be available as properties. If you're using the approach in the second box, you should have access to everything your normally would and then some. The property names would be different (since you're dealing directly with the binding elements and not a fancy, friendly canned binding type), but everything and more should be there, and you should get intellisense in Visual Studio.

Are you looking for anything in particular?

Comment: ok.. It was late on and I got myself confused!
I see now all properties are available to the subclass of WS2007FederationHttpBinding. 
I added code to it all and plumbed it into a ServiceHostFactory and it looks about right.
However, when I reference this service from another project or SVCUtil it, I see that it does (annoyingly) correctly identify it as a 'ws2007FederationHttpBinding' and not a custom binding.
This put me back to the start as I cannot figure out how to specify the Stream option (Co policy looks for config in this case).

Comment: ok. now I see - its either all programmatically, or all config.
I thought I could take approach #1 above (subclass) and then apply a config from xml of WS2007FederationHttpBinding.
Because we need to use the  xml config, I am rebuilding the full binding as a custom binding.  Makes sense when you step back for a second and RTFM :)

Comment: I might head down this road myself soon. One question springs to mind: Why isn't this enabled by default?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to enable streamed transfer mode in a custom binding since only the `BasicHttpBinding`, `NetTcpBinding` and `NetNamedPipeBinding` bindings expose the `TransferMode` property. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx) article for an example.

Comment: So I won't be able to use wsFederationHttpBinding and streaming transfer mode right?

Comment: No, but you can create a custom binding that emulates what the `WsFederationHttpBinding` binding does, just do so carefully.

Comment: Do you have any example of custom binding which emulates WsFederationHttpBinding?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. The `WsFederationHttpBinding` binding is very similar to the `WsHttpBinding` binding. Exactly why do you need to use the `WsFederationHttpBinding` binding?

Comment: We use token based authentication, we have a centralized authentication to authenticate different applications.