# Ws2007FederationHttpBinding - Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 268435456 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low

Tags: performance, wcf, wsfederationhttpbinding

We have a WCF service exposed over ws2007FederationHttpBinding binding. I am trying to access 100MB word document  over this service and getting error  as **"Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 268435456 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low.
"**
Any help on this to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Server side configuration

```
 <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message negotiateServiceCredential="false">
          <issuerMetadata address="https://abc.com/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
          <issuer address="https://abc.com/adfs/services/trust/13/kerberosmixed" />
          <claimTypeRequirements>
            <add claimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" isOptional="true" />
            <add claimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" isOptional="true" />
          </claimTypeRequirements>
        </message>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Comment: Maybe this thread?   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04a1848e-7d7f-4ecf-b6ca-771cb25f7696/failed-to-allocate-a-managed-memory-buffer-of-268435456-bytes      and setting the system.web httpRuntime maxRequestLength

Comment: This is did not help.

Comment: You will probably have to change it to use streaming rather than buffered.  See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033947/how-do-i-support-streaming-in-wsfederationhttpbinding  However as the thread says then you would need to have a custom binding that has the streaming configured as well as reproduce all the federation settings in the custom bindings.